# Can I get intellisense for chrome apps and extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, javascript-intellisense

Is there any way to get javascript `IntelliSense` for developing Google Chrome apps and extensions in Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include this file found at GitHub: [chrome.intellisense.js](https://github.com/cmc19/js-intellisense/blob/master/chrome.intellisense.js)

place the file in the same directory as the file you are working on and add the following line at the top of your source file.

```
 /// <reference path="chrome" />
```

This also works in VS 2013 and should work in Visual Studio 2010 <s>and 2013</s> as well, but is not tested.

Answer (score 3):

Solution found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/93c2ez/chrome_extension_autocomplete/)

create file `jsconfig.json` with the following content

```json
{"typeAcquisition": {"include": ["chrome"]}}
```

Comment: Any Idea why this breaks the base intellisense? For example it doesn't recognize the Promise constructor when I add this