# inclusion of chrome.intellisense.js for Chrome extensions development in Visual Studio options

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, google-chrome-extension, intellisense

According to answers to the question "Can I get intellisense for chrome apps and extensions?" ( [Can I get intellisense for chrome apps and extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21493495/11789156) ) in order to develope a Chrome extension with Visual Studio, I have included chrome.intellisense.js in the same directory of the Chrome extension being developed. The solution works for VS2019, but it is dirty having to include chrome.intellisense.js for every developed extension. Then, how can I avoid it? Is there any VS2019 option that frees me of including chrome.intellisense.js in each directory where I want to develope a Chrome extension ?

The solution of including chrome.intellisense.js in the directory works (at least for VS2019 where I am testing it), but I think it works partially, not for the whole Chrome API'ss. Even more, in VS2019 there is no need of including "/// " in the first line of the js of the extension being developed. Just include the expanded zip of chrome.intellisense.js and rename it to "chrome" and it will work: intellisense for Chrome extensions will act as desired

Can not show intellisense in action because of it pops up, but after typing "chrome." a list of methods and properties pops up, though not complete for Chrome 75.

It would be desireable a full intellisense for Chrome 75 API's

It would be desireable not having to include the file chrome.intellisense.js in the directory of .js's development.

Comment: If you haven't seen it already, this guy walks through how to do chrome extension development in VS https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185723/Develop-Your-First-Google-Chrome-Extension-Using-H

Comment: All advanced IDE should support [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/) which adds the most comprehensive support for lots of stuff including chrome API.

Comment: @mwilson.
If the API innerly pointed is directly downloaded and installed from the visualstudio marketplace, an error occurs. But I have successfully downloaded it from GitHub and I am experimenting with that API. 
It is so curious, however, surprisingly, that the extensión developer DOES NOT MAKE ANY USE OF THE API AT ALL. But it links to the API. Luck.

Comment: @wOxxOm.
Do you mean if I “npm install --save @types/chrome” I will be ready ? Do you think it matches javascript ? or Typescript ? Thanks

Comment: There might be articles about using DefinitelyTyped in VS, I just don't know. What I know is that a JetBrains IDE or VSCode or Atom can use it. Note, you may need a customized repo/fork of DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get intellisense for chrome apps and extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493495/can-i-get-intellisense-for-chrome-apps-and-extensions)

Comment: this has worked fine for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493495/can-i-get-intellisense-for-chrome-apps-and-extensions